# Can aws lambda invoke a matlab function?

Tags: node.js, matlab, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to invoke a matlab function on asking Alexa - Amazon echo. The code for amazon echo is in nodejs and I am not sure how do you make calls to matlab functions from aws lambda function.

Comment: Did you have any success ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Compile your Matlab code statically into an executable (linux 64).
In your zip file, package the lambda and just add the executable to the package and call it via your nodejs code.

Comment: Not that simple ! The MCR is gigabytes large.